# Rock Paper Scissors, with changing weapon sets and player preferences

Tags: python, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

#### The task

The goal here is to build a RPS engine that can run tournaments of RPS games between different players. The initial version has been written with the [Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors#Additional_weapons) ruleset, but it is expected that weapons will be frequently added or removed.

Within each game of RPS, each player will be restricted to a limited selection of weapons. They will choose between these weapons based on what the opponent expects to do and their own personal preference of the weapons. There are currently five players defined, but it is expected that players will frequently be added or removed.

#### Code structure

The code is spread out over five different files:

```
players.py
predictions.py
preferences.py
rps_game.py
weapons.py
```

I will present these in the order that I believe gives best readability.

#### preferences.py

This file contains each of the possible preferences. A preference represents how positively or negatively a player feels about a weapon.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Preference(object):
    """An opinion that a person can have on a weapon in RPS"""
    desc: str
    pref_value: int


PROHIBITED = Preference("This person has sworn off using this option and will never use it", pref_value=-3)
DISLIKED = Preference("This person dislikes using this option and will only use it if they consider it necessary to win", pref_value=-2)
UNFAVORABLE = Preference("This person mildly dislikes this option and will only choose it if there are no better options", pref_value=-1)
NEUTRAL = Preference("This person does not have any feelings about this option", pref_value=0)
FAVORABLE = Preference("This person mildly likes using this option and will choose it over a neutral option if both are considered equally likely to win", pref_value=1)
LIKED = Preference("This person likes using this option, and will use it unless they think it will lose them the game", pref_value=2)
NECESSARY = Preference("This person will always use this option if possible, even if they expect it to lose the game", pref_value=3)
ALL_PREFERENCES = {PROHIBITED, DISLIKED, UNFAVORABLE, NEUTRAL, FAVORABLE, LIKED, NECESSARY}
```

#### weapons.py

This file contains details on the different weapons and how they interact with each other.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Weapon(object):
    """A weapon that can be thrown in a game of Rock Paper Scissors."""
    title: str
    desc: str


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ThrowOutcome(object):
    """An object that represents the result of throwing a weapon against an opponent"""
    outcome_name: str
    outcome_verb: str
    outcome_value: int


THROW_WIN = ThrowOutcome(outcome_name='Win', outcome_verb='Won', outcome_value=1)
THROW_DRAW = ThrowOutcome(outcome_name='Draw', outcome_verb='Drew', outcome_value=0)
THROW_LOSE = ThrowOutcome(outcome_name='Lose', outcome_verb='Lost', outcome_value=-1)


def evaluate_throw(self_weapon: Weapon, opp_weapon: Weapon) -> ThrowOutcome:
    if opp_weapon in BEATEN_THROWS[self_weapon]:
        return THROW_WIN
    elif self_weapon in BEATEN_THROWS[opp_weapon]:
        return THROW_LOSE
    else:
        return THROW_DRAW


# Currently there are five possible hands, but it is expected that more weapons will frequently be added
ROCK = Weapon("Rock", "Fist with no fingers extended")
PAPER = Weapon("Paper", "All fingers and thumb extended and held together")
SCISSORS = Weapon("Scissors", "Index and middle finger extended and separated with no other fingers extended")
SPOCK = Weapon("Spock", "All fingers extended and forming a vulcan salute")
LIZARD = Weapon("Lizard", "All fingers extended and held together, thumb held underneath touching fingertips")
ALL_WEAPONS = [ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS, SPOCK, LIZARD]


# For each throw, we list the opposing throws that this beats
# This can be used to calculate all wins, losses and draws
BEATEN_THROWS = {ROCK: {SCISSORS, LIZARD},
                 PAPER: {ROCK, SPOCK},
                 SCISSORS: {PAPER, LIZARD},
                 SPOCK: {ROCK, SCISSORS},
                 LIZARD: {PAPER, SPOCK}}
```

#### predictions.py

This file is mostly placeholder logic, I'm holding off on writing the prediction logic until the rest of the code has been reviewed.

```py
import random
from dataclasses import dataclass
from weapons import Weapon
from preferences import Preference


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Prediction(object):
    """A prediction of the most likely throw in a game of RPS"""
    weapon: Weapon
    confidence: float


def make_prediction(possible_weapons: list[Weapon], preferences: dict[Weapon, Preference]) -> Prediction:
    """Make a prediction of what weapon will be thrown"""
    # This is complex logic that will be implemented later. As a placeholder, we just pick randomly.
    return Prediction(weapon=random.choice(possible_weapons), confidence=random.uniform(0, 1))
```

#### players.py

This file contains details on the players and their preferences. It also contains logic on how each player will choose weapons in each round.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import random
import weapons
import preferences
from predictions import Prediction


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Player(object):
    """A player who can participate in games of RPS"""
    name: str
    desc: str
    weapon_prefs: dict[weapons.Weapon, preferences.Preference]
    prediction_confidence_threshold: float = 0.5

    def choose_weapon(self, opp_prediction: Prediction, weapon_options: set[weapons.Weapon]) -> weapons.Weapon:
        """Of the weapons that can be chosen, chose one based on personal preferences and what the opponent is predicted to do"""
        # If there are any weapons that are considered necessary, one of those is picked, preferring ones that are expected to give a better result
        # Otherwise, we pick a weapon based on the preference and expected outcome
        # If the prediction confidence is too low, we prioritize preference, and otherwise prioritize expected result
        # If a weapon is liked, then a draw with it is considered more preferable than a win with a less preferred weapon
        # If a weapon is disliked, then a draw with it is considered less preferable than a loss with a more preferred weapon
        weapon_sort_keys = dict()
        for weapon in weapon_options:
            # We construct a sort key based on the weapon preference and expected result
            weapon_pref = self.weapon_prefs.get(weapon, preferences.NEUTRAL)
            weapon_result = weapons.evaluate_throw(weapon, opp_prediction.weapon)
            if weapon_pref == preferences.LIKED and weapon_result == weapons.THROW_DRAW:
                weapon_result_like_adjusted = weapons.THROW_WIN
            elif weapon_pref == preferences.DISLIKED and weapon_result == weapons.THROW_DRAW:
                weapon_result_like_adjusted = weapons.THROW_LOSE
            else:
                weapon_result_like_adjusted = weapon_result
            sort_key = (
                1 if weapon_pref == preferences.NECESSARY else 0,
                weapon_result_like_adjusted.outcome_value if opp_prediction.confidence > self.prediction_confidence_threshold else 0,
                weapon_pref.pref_value,
                weapon_result.outcome_value,
                random.uniform(0, 1)
            )
            weapon_sort_keys[weapon] = sort_key
        sorted_weapons = sorted(weapon_options, key=lambda x: weapon_sort_keys[x], reverse=True)
        return sorted_weapons[0]


# The number of players is expected to increase frequently
ALL_PLAYERS = [
    Player(name='Norman',
           desc='Norman finds the classic three weapons boring and likes the novelty of the new weapons',
           weapon_prefs={weapons.ROCK: preferences.UNFAVORABLE,
                         weapons.PAPER: preferences.UNFAVORABLE,
                         weapons.SCISSORS: preferences.UNFAVORABLE}),
    Player(name='Susan',
           desc='Susan likes the letter S, as well as weapons that contain the letter S',
           weapon_prefs={weapons.SCISSORS: preferences.NECESSARY,
                         weapons.SPOCK: preferences.LIKED}),
    Player(name='Clive',
           desc='Clive likes the classic three weapons and really dislikes Spock',
           weapon_prefs={weapons.ROCK: preferences.FAVORABLE,
                         weapons.PAPER: preferences.FAVORABLE,
                         weapons.SCISSORS: preferences.FAVORABLE,
                         weapons.SPOCK: preferences.PROHIBITED}),
    Player(name='Elizabeth',
           desc='Elizabeth dislikes throwing lizards, as the hand shape resembles sock puppets too much',
           weapon_prefs={weapons.LIZARD: preferences.DISLIKED}),
    Player(name='Alan',
           desc='Alan likes all weapons equally and just wants to win',
           weapon_prefs={})
]
```

#### rps_game.py

This file contains code that will run tournaments of each player against each other and print the details of each game in the tournament.

```py
import players
import weapons
from predictions import make_prediction
import random
import math


class RpsTournament(object):
    """An object that will run a series of RPS games against different players"""

    @staticmethod
    def run_single_game(p1: players.Player, p2: players.Player) -> None:
        """Run a single game of RPS between two players"""
        print(f"Starting game between {p1.name} and {p2.name}")
        # Each player is limited to half (rounded up) of the possible weapons, chosen randomly
        num_weapons = math.ceil(len(weapons.ALL_WEAPONS)/2)
        p1_weapons = random.sample(weapons.ALL_WEAPONS, num_weapons)
        p2_weapons = random.sample(weapons.ALL_WEAPONS, num_weapons)
        p1_prediction = make_prediction(p1_weapons, p1.weapon_prefs)
        p2_prediction = make_prediction(p2_weapons, p2.weapon_prefs)
        print(f"{p1.name} is predicted to throw {p1_prediction.weapon.title} ({p1_prediction.confidence:.2f}) from {[w.title for w in p1_weapons]}")
        print(f"{p2.name} is predicted to throw {p2_prediction.weapon.title} ({p2_prediction.confidence:.2f}) from {[w.title for w in p2_weapons]}")
        p1_chosen_weapon = p1.choose_weapon(p2_prediction, p1_weapons)
        p2_chosen_weapon = p2.choose_weapon(p1_prediction, p2_weapons)
        throw_result = weapons.evaluate_throw(p1_chosen_weapon, p2_chosen_weapon)
        print(f"{p1.name} has {throw_result.outcome_verb} against {p2.name} ({p1_chosen_weapon.title} vs {p2_chosen_weapon.title})")

    def run_tournament(self) -> None:
        for p1 in players.ALL_PLAYERS:
            for p2 in players.ALL_PLAYERS:
                if p1.name != p2.name:
                    self.run_single_game(p1, p2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tournament = RpsTournament()
    tournament.run_tournament()
```

#### My thoughts so far

Having written this, there are a few areas that I feel could likely be improved, but I can't see a way to do so without introducing other potential issues:

- I have implemented every weapon and every preference as a constant, which feels like a lot of constants for a python script. I could treat them like the players (who do not get a constant for each player and instead a single list that contains all the players), but that would make it tricky to define the weapon preferences for each player without using a lot of magic words.
- I have a lot of ranked dataclasses, where I give the rank of each dataclass manually (e.g.  preferences are ranked by `pref_value`). This feels unpythonic, and I feel like there would be a better way of doing this using an `enum` or similar construction.
- There are cases where I have to repeat the names of objects. For instance, I have to write the work 'ROCK' twice when I call `ROCK = Weapon("Rock")`. This feels unpythonic, but I cannot think of a better way of doing it.

Comment: A comment and a question: There is no need to explicitly state that `RpsTournament` is a subclass of `object`.  Why have you chosen to make  `RpsTournament.run_single_game` a static method but `RpsTournament.run_tournament` not a static method (it` doesn't reference any instance methods or attributes),

Comment: @Booboo It is planned the future developments would add more functionality to tournaments (e.g. adding or removing players, running under different rulesets) that would make `run_tournament` not suitable as a static method.

Comment: I get what you are saying completely so by the same logic you might not want to have `run_single_game` be a static method.

Comment: @Booboo a valid point, `run_single_game` should probably not be static either.